# How to see changes on live after taking latest code base pull in aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitlab, was

my website(a MERN app) is live on aws and running with ec2 instance. I m using gitlab repo. So I developed some minor modules in my project and pushed it to gitlab(master branch). now I opened ssh ec2 instance terminal by using ssh -I .... ubuntu@xxxx... and its connected successfully from ec2 instance server. Then I went in my project folder by cd /var/www/my_Projectrepo/ 
and took pull from gitlab master by(git pull origin master), in terminal there I can see my files which I added in my last commit. But when I am visiting my site live (https://www.myproject.com) I can't able to see my latest changes. I also restart the Nginx & pm2 but not worked. Please help me out from this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If the files are in the correct location and have the correct owner, then it could be either a server or browser caching issue.  Or Content Delivery Network caching if using a CDN.

Comment: thanks @DaveS, yes files are in my project folder. What do you mean by correct owner? means repo owner?

Comment: By owner I meant the files have an owner that gives all needed access rights with the web server user.  If this is the first time that files have been copied to the server this way the SSH user is probably different from the web user and the pull might not set permissions the way you need them. Caching is a more likely cause but that's just one more thing to check.

Comment: @ChandanKumar were you able to solve this?